# How to return a tree of react tags from a Map() object in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to return a return a structure like :

```
<div>
  <div label=Category 1>
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div label=Category 2>
    <ul>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to achieve this, I created a Map() object an I want to iterate through categories and items. Desperately tried all sorts of ideas with no luck. I am not sure if is very simple or impossible in react. I am imagining to run stg. like this and 1) yet it does not return any value 2) splitting the ul tag is not allowed, apparently.

```
  for (let [key, values] of lists) {
    <div label={key}><ul>;
    values.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>);
    </ul>
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how you create lists? Is it a Map like in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map or just an object that's being used as a map?

Comment: Please see my edit, for usage with a Map().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working version of @Expressd3v's code (possibly with a couple of edits). I tried to add this to @Expressd3v answer but the edit's not been approved so maybe that wasn't the right way to go about it. Please don't upvote this as it's basically @Expressd3v answer.

Edited to use Map().

```js
const Lists = ({ lists }) =>
  <React.Fragment>
    {
      [...lists].map(([key, values]) => (
        <div label={key} key={key}>
          <ul>
            { values.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>) }
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </React.Fragment>;

const App = () => {
  let lists = new Map();
  lists.set('Category 1', [
    { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
  ]);
  lists.set('Category 2', [
    { id: 3, name: 'item3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'item4' },
  ]);
  
  return <Lists lists={lists} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes @Ben, that worked !! I will look into it separately but what is the philosophy behind using "ellipsis" for Maps ? I thought it was used typically for "rest of arguments" in a function. Also, please advice how I should credit  between you or Expressd3v. Cheers

Comment: @GeoSystems I just used one of the methods found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#relation_with_array_objects , however `...` is used in two ways, one is the rest parameter syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters , the other is spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax . I don't really have any idea about credit, maybe neither if that's an option, until @Expressd3v's answer works.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I accepted your answer as 1) your version does work with the Map object 2) Your time and synchronized comms 3) guidance on the API specs. Thanks a lot to you and also Express !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Missing

For loop is not returning any value.
So you need to include a return.

for example:

```
 for (let [key, values] of lists) {
   return(
     <div label={key}>
        <ul>
          {values.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>);}
        </ul>
      </div>
   )
  }
```

2. My suggestion

```
Object.entries(lists).map(([key,values])=>(
   <div label={key} key={key}>
     <ul>
        {values.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}
     </ul>
   </div>
  )
))
```

Comment: I think there might be a couple of issues with this answer. 1) `values.map(...)` should be in `{ }`. 2) I don't think your first example would work because it would return for the function containing the for loop rather than each element in the list. 3) I'm not sure, but the `;` after `values.map(...)` might not be wanted here.

Comment: map loop can be in `( )`. And I wish to suggest you to try my solution. Thank you

Comment: The map function body can be in `( )` for sure. But the javascript code between `<ul>` and `</ul>` needs to be in `{ }`.

Comment: And then use that with the return. I updated the post

Comment: Those `( )` were fine before (without the return). `<ul> values.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>); </ul>` needs to be `<ul> { values.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>) } </ul>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231259/discussion-between-ben-stephens-and-expressd3v).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I am probably closer to solution but not exactly. Couple of points :

Comment: 1) As @BenStephens mentioned, both snippets did not like the semicolon ";", so I removed it. 2) for loop runs but only for the first category and then loops out; i.e. does not run for the second category. 3) Object.entries loop returns a "Nothing was returned from render" error. I can see in the debugger that code runs over the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update @BenStephens ! It did not work for me due to the semantic differences of these objects. Please see the difference below :<console>Map(2) {nouns => (3) [{…}, {…}, …], verbs => (2) [{…}, {…}]} versus

{Category 1: Array(2), Category 2: Array(2)}</console>. Mine is a Map() object, yours is an object with attributes. Apparently they are not the same.